# Ошибка из-за android:targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, java

Приложение не работает когда в Manifest прописан android:targetSdkVersion

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Если убрать targetSdkVersion то приложение работает, завершается приложение с ошибкой на предпоследней строке кода где authtoken. Но я уверен что дело не в этой строке(потому что раньше я отсылал POST-запрос другим методом и с targetSdkVersion тоже не работало), а там где authtoken присваивается.

Часть кода отправки POST-запроса уже с auth_token

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                    "сайт");
            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder
                    .create();
            multipartEntity.setBoundary(boundary);
            Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            multipartEntity.setCharset(chars);
            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    multipartEntity.addTextBody("auth_token", authtoken, TEXT_PLAIN);
            post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
```

Ниже часть кода где я авторизуюсь POST-запросом и получаю ответ от сервера в виде json строки и потом достаю от туда auth_token.

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        String json;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        JSONParser par = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsobj = (JSONObject) par.parse(json);
        authtoken = jsobj.get("auth_token").toString();
```

Повторюсь что без targetSdkVersion программа работает на android-устройствах без ошибок.

**UPD**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody.<init>(StringBody.java:159)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:121)
at ru.dfort.advert.PostAdv.post(PostAdv.java:75) // Отправка с auth_token
at ru.dfort.advert.MainAdvert$1$1.onClick(MainAdvert.java:79) //вызов функции post
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:169)
```

Comment: Я уже устал задавать этот вопрос... "С какой ошибкой???" 
Сегодня Сатурн не в Юпитере, и мой хрустальный шар немного поцарапан, по этому экран ваш в нем немного размыт, и я не могу рассмотреть, что там за ошибка?

Comment: @metalurgus, в апдейте

Comment: из документации по Андроиду:    
android:targetSdkVersion
An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.   
То есть, если вы не указываете android:targetSdkVersion, то по умолчанию будет использован тот же, что и minSdkVersion.    
Видимо, что-то поменялось между 7 и 19 SDK.    
А вы часом не в главном потоке с сетью работаете?

Comment: Видимо в главном :) Но я об этом пока не слышал, где можно почитать про это? Вызывается эта функция из главного activity, функция типа void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после 7 (или 8, точно не помню) версии, запрещено выполнять операции с сетью на главном потоке (UI-thread), т. к. это вешает программу на неопределенный промежуток времени, что само по себе выглядит ужасно.  
Теперь операции с сетью надо выполнять во второстепенных потоках, на пример при помощи **AsyncTask**. Больше можно узнать в гугле, на пример по запросу [android network asynctask](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+network+asynctask)